# Loud water sounds when tub faucet is turned on

Tags: faucet, bathtub, sound-proofing

I have the Alder tub/shower combo (http://www.moen.com/adler/spot-resist-brushed-nickel-posi-temp-r-tub-shower/_/R-CONSUMER%3AL82694EPSRN).  When I turn on the water for the tub, the sounds of water are very loud!  I can hear water (flowing through pipes, I think) through the walls in adjacent rooms.

When I turn the diverter to the shower head, this sound goes away (I think because the flow of water is a lot lower for the shower head).

I suspect the sound is happening because the water pressure is high and the volume of water flowing through the tub spout is also very high.

What are my options to reduce the noise in the other rooms?  I looked for an aerator for the tub but it doesn't seem to exist (and it's a weird rectangular shaped spout, not standard circle).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The noise may be caused by [harmonic vibrations](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/sound/Lesson-4/Fundamental-Frequency-and-Harmonics). Try adjusting the flow by opening the tap less, the downside is that it will take longer for the tub to fill.

Other options tend to be more invasive, like opening up the walls and/or ceiling and strapping the supply piping tightly.

You could try a new tub spout, one which delivers more or less water per time unit, or has different flow characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a Shut-Off valve that you can access. Jimmy Fix-it was right about the harmonic imbalance. You would start closing the shut-Off valve while the tub is filling & just turn the valve down enough to get rid of the noise & clanking. Usually, there's no affect to water flow as you're just capping off the flow very slightly.